# Setting web page background color

Tags: javascript, html

I can set the background color of the current page using:

```
 document.body.style.background='red';
```

Is there any way I can set the color of a page from another page?

**Note:** I can set the color when a page contains frames. In this case, consider the scenario similar to two different tabs of a browser.

Comment: If you're opening the second page from the first, could you get the color from the first and pass it in the query string to the second?

Comment: Consider this: Two pages are opened... The color is set in one page... Upon refresh the color of the second page must change...!

Comment: @gir3191 The only way to do that is to have the colour of the first page saved as a resource that both pages can access, such as [client-side document storage](http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html) or a database.

Comment: @Chris Francis: Interesting article... Any other references...?

Comment: Well the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage) has some decent stuff, and [this tutorial](http://html5tutorial.net/tutorials/working-with-html5-localstorage.html) seems to give a reasonable explanation of the basics.

Comment: @Chris Francis: thanx... w'll give it a read...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, providing:

1. You have a reference to the other page (such as the return value of `window.open`)
2. The page is on the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Then just use said reference.

Answer (score 0):

John K's comment is a good solution. If you're loading the other page synchronously (ie full page load, not AJAX) then obviously you're going to have to maintain the state between pages. The very nature of HTTP is pretty stateless, so a query-string is a nice simple solution for persisting data such as a background colour.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set apge background color using javascript, you can **document.body.style.backgroundColor** in your js code.

And if you want to set the bgcolor of a page from another page you need to use query string and pass the color in a variable to the other page and set the other page background color using that variable value on page load or whatever way you want.

Comment: are you asking for any other method to accomplish this?

Comment: yes... and this could be done only for pages on the same domain...?

Answer (score -3):

seems only if you have opener.

Comment: why not?
he asked _how can he change color of anothe page_
one of the way is to use opener as folow:
`<body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (!opener)
                var win = window.open('opener.html');
            else {
                opener.document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }
        </script>
    </body>`

Comment: It only makes sense if you recognise the `opener` object (which you probably wouldn't if you were asking the question).

Comment: @Chris Francis 
actualy YES.

@Quentin
and what the problem with opener recognition?

Comment: @Subdigger, @Quentin - is the `opener` object a fully fledged DOM Window? From my testing here in Chrome it is simply a boolean.

Comment: @Subdigger — The problem is that if you don't know what it is, then your answer gives no hint that it is a programming construct, and the answer looks like a nonsense sentence.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for that, it seems as though Chrome isn't fulfilling that spec then, as I'm seeing an object called `DOMWindow` but instead of having a full DOM it's just a single `true` value. Strange...